# How to restore python to its default on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I was trying to finish a project using python 2.7, so that I installed python version 2.7.6 into my system. But now my system is not functioning properly & some apps aren't working.

How do I go back and restore the python to its default?

Comment: How did you installed it?

Comment: Python should be backwards compatible, no? I get py3 and py2, but not py2.7 to py2.7.6

Comment: i used this tutorial

http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered here with `update-alternatives`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140731/1041104

A detailed response is outlined here:

http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/update-alternatives-in-debian/