# Cannot install new version of python 2.7

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python, make

I keep getting stuck on one esoteric error after another. I am simply trying to upgrade my existing Python 2.7.6 to 2.7.12. Thats all I want to do!

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu), and make it all the way to the `sudo checkinstall` command.

However after I execute it, I get a huge list of (seemingly) ok stuff, followed by:

```
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/parsers/expat.py ...
Listing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/_exceptions.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/handler.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

I'm getting really frustrated as I don't think this should be this hard... what am I missing? FWIW, I am working in a pip virtual environment.

Thanks.

Comment: "Shouldn't be this hard" is the name of the game with Linux.Ubuntu already has python 2.7 installed, you can try and first rename /usr/local/lib/python2.7 or wherever you have it.