# Where do I find Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python-2.7

I'm really noob at Ubuntu and I really need Phython 2.7 and PIP next week on our training.

The instruction are to:
-Install Ubuntu
-Install Python
-Install  - python2.7-dev - python-dev
-And PIP

So I tried to install some stuff and research stuff. Like installing Python 2.7.13 and fiddle with the terminal and stuff.

The problem is. I don't know where to open the Python that I have installed or to install the next thing PIP.

[How do I install the latest Python 2.7.X or 3.X on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu) - Here are the steps that I have followed.

If you have time, please do a step-by-step and explain it to me so I can understand. What I'm doing. Really lost right now. D:

Comment: -Anyone- on Ubuntu has python 2.7 installed. Type `which python` on command line. And type `python` to enter command line. Otherwise use an editor.  And the `dev` and `pip`: `sudo apt-get install` with the package name to install these. Your task to find the package names (hint: start with the names you typed ;-) )

Comment: sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo apt-get install pip

Like that or not?

Answer (score 7):

Both Python 2 and 3 come pre-installed with Ubuntu by default. There is no need to compile from source.

To open python2, just run:

```
python
```

And to open python3, just run:

```
python3
```

---

To find the location of the python2 binary, just run:

```
which python
```

And to find the location of the python3 binary:

```
which python3
```

Comment: do I need to run it from terminal?

Comment: I really apologize if I don't know anything.

Comment: @vonvonvon - Running from the terminal as opposed to what?

Comment: so the terminal has this ">>>" thingy?
Is that the python?

Comment: @vonvonvon - That's the live python shell interpreter. If you want to run a `.py` file, then you just do `python fileInQuestion.py`

Comment: So I tried to create a new file using "touch newfile.py" so I can open the interface and get familiar with it. Where did that file go?

Comment: under the right click. I can't seem to find a command to create a new file there. So I used the terminal

Comment: @vonvonvon if you want an integrated development environment (IDE) for python, you can install `idle` (or `idle3` for python3). Otherwise, you can use any plain text editor to *write* your code, and then *run* it in the terminal.

Comment: Oh so. The Shell Interpreter Runs the code that I have wrote. Thanks. :) Btw how do I check if I got the  "python2.7-dev - python-dev And PIP" installed already? I tried to fiddle with Sudo and I don't know if I got it right,

Comment: @vonvonvon please resist the temptation to *"fiddle with sudo"*. You can see the installed status using `apt-cache policy python2.7 python-dev python-pip`

Comment: sorry not gonna fiddle it anymore. hahaha. anyway thanks man. :)