# Python version 2.7.13, PIP has unmet dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

I am completely new to Ubuntu, am using version 16.04. I installed Python 2.7.13 using this link: [How do I install the latest Python 2.7.X or 3.X on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu)

and then used this link to install PIP: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04/

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

but was given the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-pip : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
          Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
          Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I double checked which Python version I have:

```
python -V
```

and I have python 2.7.13, so I don't understand how the dependencies aren't met.

Was Python already installed when I installed Ubuntu and somehow installing it again screwed me up?

Comment: *Was Python already installed when I installed Ubuntu and somehow installing it again screwed me up?* YES!!!

Comment: Oops! Is it an easy remedy to uninstall the one I installed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the foggiest idea.

Comment: When you run `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt install python-pip`, is anything different? [Which way](https://askubuntu.com/q/101591) did you install 2.7.13? Please **[edit]** with the commands you ran. (The `history` command may help.) Do you need 2.7.13, or is 2.7.12 (which is in Ubuntu 16.04's official repositories) sufficient? The differences are small; if you need 2.7.13, you know. What's the output of *(1)* `type -a python{,2,3}`, *(2)* `namei $(command -v python{,2,3})`, and *(3)* `apt list python 'python[23].[0-9]' 'python*minimal'`? Please put it all in your **[edit]**--thanks!