# Upgrade to python 2.7.15 (for gdb 8) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, python, g++, gdb

I am running `Ubuntu 16.04` with `gdb` version `7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5`. When I upgraded `g++` to `g++-6.4` (`Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1~16.04`), gdb started giving python errors like:

```
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object: 
Error while executing Python code.
```

whenever I try to print a class or an STL object during debugging. I determined that only `gdb-8` supports `g++-6.4`, so I tried to build `gdb-8.1` from the instructions on http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/gdb.html, but `gdb-8.1` requires `python 2.7.15`, and just installing `gdb-8.1` without upgrading python (installed version is `2.7.12`) did not solve the printing issues.

Following the accepted answer at [How do I install the latest Python 2.7.X or 3.X on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu), I tried to install `python 2.7.15` from the `deadsnakes` ppa. But, mysteriously, `python 2.7.xx` is not even listed on the ppa page (https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), even though `2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6` are all available. Then, I tried to build it manually based on instructions at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html, but it turns out that `python 2.7.15` gets installed in a separate location (`/usr/local/bin` etc.) and does not replace `python 2.7.12`. So the gdb printing errors are still present.

Is there a way to completely replace the installed `python 2.7.12`? Even if I can use the correct python binary file, I will have to change the library location for the dev files to that from the new version and may be rebuild `gdb-8.1` against those python-dev files. Because otherwise, I see errors such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/__init__.py", line 144, in auto_load_packages
   __import__(modname)
 File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/command/pretty_printers.py", line 19, in <module>
   import copy
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
   import weakref
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
   from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

when I start `gdb`. If nothing helps, I might have to upgrade (not desirable) to `Ubuntu-18.04` which ships with `python 2.7.15rc` and `gdb-7`, though `gdb-8` experimental version is available from the repositories.

Similar questions to this have not been as specific and haven't helped me solve the problem.