# How to upgrade Python to the latest version

Tags: upgrade, python

I have the following version of Python, in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.17
python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

How to upgrade it to the latest version 3.8.2
 I have already run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.8.2
```

However, that did not make any changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest Python 2.7.X or 3.X on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-the-latest-python-2-7-x-or-3-x-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like binary packages in Ubuntu for python are up to 3.6.9.
I think you would need to download required version of Python from
[Python relesases](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and then follow documentation.

Comment: What are the steps for that?

Comment: Parichay Pari, please note that no Python can be "upgraded", as the system versions are used by the admin tools, e.g. `apt`. .... I.e. a change will make the OS invalid.

Comment: In tar.gz folder you need to see README file and look at installing multiple versions of Python, e.g.:
`./configure`
    `make`
    `make test`
    `sudo make altinstall --prefix <INSTALL_DIR>`